# Inserting nodes in a binary search tree (C)

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a function to insert a node to a binary search tree, and I have the following:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int key;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
} Node;

Node *createNode(int key)
{
    Node *newNode = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

Node *insert(Node *node, int key)
{
    if (node==NULL)
    {
        node = createNode(key);
    }
    else
    {
        if (node->key > key)
        {
            node->left = insert(node->left, key);
        }
        else
        {
            node->right = insert(node->right, key);
        }
    }
    return node;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Node *root = NULL;
    root = insert(root, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

I know this works, and if I want to insert 5 to the tree with root node `root`, I can write `root = insert(root, 5);`. My question is, how can I write another version of `insert` that can achieve the same thing with simply `insert(root, 5);`? I have tried the following but with no avail.

```
void insert(Node *node, int key)
{
    if (node==NULL)
    {
        node = createNode(key);
    }
    else
    {
        if (node->key > key)
        {
            insert(node->left, key);
        }
        else
        {
            insert(node->right, key);
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this and why doesn't this work?. Any pointers (no pun intended) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Short answer: no. there are cases where you need to change root's value. (for example: when the tree is empty, and root is NULL) One way is by means of an assignmnt using the return value (as in your working example) The other way is passing a pointer to pointer. (a pointer to root) to the function.

Comment: The reason being, that when you insert a value in a BST, you have to insure that the BST *remains* a BST, (e.g. the left child contains nodes with values less than the parent node and where the right child only contains nodes with values greater than or equal to the parent.). This means you will have to check for several conditions on insertion and you may have to move a node or leaf (or the root node) around to satisfy the BST constraints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, your first solution is elegant.

Now, if you want to insert without taking advantage of return value, then a way could be using a pointer to pointer.

Something like:

```
void insert(Node ** node, int key)
{
    if (*node == NULL)
      *node = createNode(key);
    else if ((*node)->key > key)
      insert(&(*node)->left, key);
    else
      insert(&(*node)->right, key);
}
```

And the call would be

```
insert(&root, 10);
```